# Split really long caption in two columns

Tags: floats, captions, two-column

I have a 2 columns document and I have an Image which goes on one column (the left one). The image fits inside the column but the caption is too long, so it doesn't respect the page borders, it overpasses the borders and disappears when the page is over.
How do I impose the caption to continue on the second column (right one)?

This is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{figure}[p]

\includegraphics{img1.pdf} 

\caption{\small \sl Really long caption.....}

\label{fig:Fig1}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable resulting in your issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! With the `caption`  package, you can specify the caption width, this way: `\caption[font=\columnwidth, font=small]{…}`